# How to disable or remove the predefined setting for long press Home button in Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, home-button

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 running  Lollipop 5.0 update. The phone's OS has designated the long Home button function (hold it down) to access the task manager.  I want to disable, remove or change this function.

I have tried eight different applications for Home buttons and none of them work as they only work for one or two tap functions.  While this may not sound major, it is very major to me and my needs.  I only need to be able to access the task manager from settings.

Samsung has advised that I can't change it.  I have searched the internet and forums high and low with no result.

I have never installed a new OS or anything like that, but I will have to get rid of my phone if I can't fix this problem.

Comment: Do you not have the related settings under "Settings -> Buttons"? Is the device rooted?

Comment: No, there is no button option under settings.  I am not sure if it is rooted or not?  I have never done anything to the phone or changed the OS.